# proceeedToCheckOut(){} function does not seem to be flowing through entirely

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

```
  proceedToCheckout() {
this.authService.observeAuthState((user) => {
  if (user) {
    this.userEmail = user.email;
    this.productService.getUserId(this.userEmail).then((userId) => {
      console.log(userId);
      this.productService.getUsersProduct(userId).then((productIds) => {
        console.log(productIds);

        const productObservables = productIds.map((productId) =>
          this.productService.getProductById(productId)
        );
        console.log(productObservables)

        forkJoin(productObservables).subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
          // Now you have the actual products corresponding to the product IDs
          console.log('Products:', products);

          // Iterate over the products and update quantities in Firebase
          products.forEach((product) => {
            const newQuantity = this.tempQuantities.get(product.id) || 1;

            // Use the public productRef method
            const collectionRef = this.productService.productRefs();

            // Pass the correct CollectionReference to updateProductQuantity
            this.productService.updateProductQuantity(collectionRef, product.id, newQuantity).then(() => {
              console.log('Quantity updated successfully');
            });
          });


          // Clear temporary quantities map after updating Firebase
          this.tempQuantities = new Map();
        });
      });
    });
  }
});}
```

above is my proceedToCheckOut() function which uses the users id to retrieve their cart details in the firebase. The quantity is working fine in a sense where if i adjust the quantity, the tempQuantity passes through in console.log however it does not change the quantity in the firebase. For some reason, (correct me if im wrong) the flow stops right before forkjoin. Im not sure what is causing this to happen

```
  getUsersProduct(id: string): Promise<any> {
return firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(id).get().then(doc => {
  if (doc.exists) {
    // Assuming 'cart' is the field you want to retrieve
    const cartData = doc.data()['Cart']

    return cartData;
  } else {
    // Handle the case where the document doesn't exist
    return null;
  }
});}
```

getUsersProduct function in my product.services.ts file^

```
 getProductById(id: string): Observable<Product> {
return new Observable(observer => {
  this.productRef.doc(id).get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
      const product = new Product(
        doc.data()['prod_biod'] || '',
        doc.data()['prod_cat'] || 0,
        doc.data()['prod_delivery_prog'],
        doc.data()['prod_desc'],
        doc.data()['image'],
        doc.data()['prod_manu'],
        doc.data()['prod_mat'],
        doc.data()['prod_name'],
        doc.data()['prod_orig'],
        doc.data()['prod_quantity'],
        doc.data()['prod_ratingno'],
        doc.data()['ratings'],
        doc.data()['prod_size'],
        doc.data()['shopping-cart'],
        doc.id,
  );
      observer.next(product);
    } else {
      observer.next(null);
    }
  }).catch((error) => {
    observer.error(error);
  });
});}
```

getProductById within product.services.ts^

```
    <ion-header [translucent]="true">
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Shopping Cart</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <ion-grid style="border: 1px solid; margin-right: 100px; margin-left: 100px; margin-top: 20px;">
    <ion-row *ngFor="let item of products">
      <ion-col size="auto">
        <div>
          <img [src]="item.image" alt="Product Image">
        </div>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <div>{{ item.prod_name }}</div>
        <div>
        </div>
        <!-- Use ionChange to handle input changes -->
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: flex-end; align-items: center;">
          <!-- Use separate buttons for increment and decrement -->
          <ion-button (click)="decrementQuantity(item.id)" style="margin-left: 10px;">-</ion-button>
          <ion-input
            type="number"
            [value]="tempQuantities.get(item.id)"
            (ionChange)="onQuantityChange(item.id, $event)"
            text-center
            style="max-width: 50px;"
          ></ion-input>
          <ion-button (click)="incrementQuantity(item.id)" style="margin-right: 10px;">+</ion-button>
        </div>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
  <ion-row style="margin-top: 20px; justify-content: flex-end; margin-right: 20px;">
    <ion-button expand="block" color="success" (click)="proceedToCheckout()">Proceed to Checkout</ion-button>
  </ion-row>
</ion-content>
```

^is my shopping-cart.page.html

if there is anything u need me to add in i will edit it here

edit below:

```
proceedToCheckout() {
  this.authService.observeAuthState((user) => {
    if (user) {
      this.userEmail = user.email;
      this.productService.getUserId(this.userEmail).then((userId) => {
        console.log(userId);
        this.productService.getUsersProduct(userId).then((productIds) => {
          console.log(productIds);

          const productObservables = productIds.map((productId) =>
            this.productService.getProductById(productId)
          );

          // Use combineLatest instead of forkJoin
          combineLatest(productObservables).subscribe((products: Product[]) => {
            // Now you have the actual products corresponding to the product IDs
            console.log('Products:', products);

            // Iterate over the products and update quantities in Firebase
            products.forEach((product) => {
              const newQuantity = this.tempQuantities.get(product.id) || 1;

              // Pass the correct CollectionReference to updateProductQuantity
              this.productService.updateProductQuantity(product.id, newQuantity).then(() => {
                console.log('Quantity updated successfully');
              }).catch((error) => {
                console.error('Error updating quantity:', error);
              });
            });

            // Optionally, you can update your component's products array
            // this.products = products;

            // Clear temporary quantities map after updating Firebase
            this.tempQuantities = new Map();
          });
        });
      });
    }
  });
}
```

this is my new proceedToCheckout() function. Changed up the operators from forkJoin to combineLatest. Dont exactly know how it managed to work on combineLatest and not forkJoin but now it works for me!